# Problem trying to start MySQL service in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, mysql, services

When I try to start the mysql service the server shows this

```
$ sudo service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with 
error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" 
for details.
```

When run `systemctl status mysql.service` I get this:

[image: Info with systemctl status mysql.service]

When I run `sudo journalctl -xe` I see:

[image: Info with sudo journalctl -xe]

In summary, the service MySQL does not start

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It would be preferable if you could copy the terminal output as plain text (code formatted) instead of placing screenshots in your question. Having text output allows copy-pasting of parts of it and searching for it.